# CSS class selector not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a custom alert box using HTML and CSS. The container has the id "`xAlert`" and has 3 `div`s in it: one for the title, one for the description, and one for the actions (like OK or Cancel). Here is my code so far:

```css
#xAlert{
  width:368px; /* 400-16*2 */
  max-height:200px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-200px;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:auto;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:16px;
}

.alertTitle{
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="xAlert">
    
    <div class="alertTitle">
      Alert Title
    </div>
    
    <div class="alert_description">
      Alert Description
    </div>
    
    <div class="alert_actions">
      Alert Actions
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

As you can see, the alert title (`.alertTitle`) does not have the font size of 20px. I tried using inline CSS and it worked, and I removed the CSS for `#xAlert` and it worked, but why is this not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run your code through [a validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) which says:

> Lexical error at line 9, column 2. Encountered: "\u007f" (127), after : "" } .alertTitle{ font-size:20px; }

You have an invisible character just after the first `}` which is treated as an (invalid) part of the following selector. Delete it.

Comment: Wow, okay. Thanks. I can't accept your answer now though (requires 7 more minutes).