# error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document php error

Tags: php

what is wrong with this php code?

```
<?php
function ScanDirectory($Directory, $tableau=false){
    $slash = '';
    $MyDirectory = opendir($Directory) or die('Hiba');
    while($Entry = @readdir($MyDirectory)){
        if($Entry != '.' && $Entry != '..' && $Entry != 'index.php' && $Entry != ".htaccess" && $Entry != "indexold.php" && $Entry != "test.php" && $Entry != "libraries"){
            if(is_dir($Directory.'/'.$Entry)&& $Entry != '.' && $Entry != '..'){
                $slash = '/';           
            }
            else
            {
             $slash = '';
            }
            $tableau[] = substr($Directory.'/'.$Entry, strlen(strstr($Directory.'/'.$Entry, '/', true))+1).$slash;
        }
        if(is_dir($Directory.'/'.$Entry)&& $Entry != '.' && $Entry != '..'){
            $tableau = ScanDirectory($Directory.'/'.$Entry, $tableau);
        }
    }
    closedir($MyDirectory);
    return $tableau;
}

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

$base = $xml->addChild('ListBucketResult');
$base->addChild('Name', "ressource");
$base->addChild('Prefix');
$base->addChild('Marker');
$base->addChild('MaxKeys', "1000");
$base->addChild('IsTruncated', 'false');

foreach(ScanDirectory('.') as $key => $value){
    $stat = stat($value);
    $content = $base->addChild('Contents');
    $content->addChild('Key', $value);
    $content->addChild('LastModified', date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z", filemtime($value)));

    if(is_dir($value)&& $value != '.' && $value != '..'){
        $content->addChild('ETag', '"'.md5($value).'"');
        $content->addChild('Size', 0);
    }else{
        $content->addChild('Size', $stat['size']);
        $content->addChild('ETag', '"'.md5_file($value).'"');
    }
    $content->addChild('StorageClass', 'STANDARD');
}

print($xml->asXML());
?>
```

When i load up the page it says: error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Comment: I'm not into PHP, but you could try checking if there happens to be any invisible characters at the end of the document (this happened to me once, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38687236/5116614)

Comment: No, there is no invisible characters. I don't know what is the problem, i just try to validate it, it says: Lexical error at line 1, column 2. Encountered: "?" (63), after : "<"

Comment: What do you see if you do `View Source` in the browser?

Comment: If the result contains `<?`, it suggests that the script isn't being run by the PHP interpreter. Are you accessing the script from a local file instead of a server?

Comment: I send the webpage's link, here is: http://users.atw.hu/goldgamingmc/ressource/